# Two Collections in one Each loop

Tags: meteor

Collection "notes" (markdown): `meteor **amazing**` and `reactjs *learning next*`

Collection "links": `google - www.google.com` and `stackoverflow - www.stackoverflow.com`

---

I want to display the notes and links in ONE LIST sorted by the creation date:

```
1. google - www.google.com
2. meteor - amazing
3. reactjs - learning next
4. stackoverflow - www.stackoverflow.com
```

and NOT like that:

```
1. meteor - amazing
2. reactjs - learning next

1. google - www.google.com
2. stackoverflow - www.stackoverflow.com
```

---

The "notes" and "links" collections have a completely different structure:

```
notes = new Mongo.Collection('notes');
  {{#each note}}
      {filename}}
      {{#markdown}} {{note}} {{/markdown}}
  {{/each}}


links = new Mongo.Collection('links');
  {{#each link}}
      {filename}}
      <a href={{link}}> {{link}} </a>
  {{/each}}
```

---

**QUESTION:**
**Should I have one collection for both of them? Is there a Package for this? Or how can I solve this?**

If one Item is changed, only this Item should be rendered again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `.fetch()` the documents and keys you want from each collection.
2. `.map()` the keys from each array into a set of common keys
3. You'll now have two arrays with common keys
4. Append one array to the other
5. Sort the whole array by the key you want to sort by
6. Return that array from your helper
7. Display in a single template

Alternatively you can omit step 2 and keep each document in its original structure but then your template is going to have to recognize what kind of document its rendering and display it accordingly.

Comment: Should I then do something like that?

Comment: {{#if note}} 
    {{#markdown}} {{note}} {{/markdown}}
{{/if}}

Comment: {{#if link}} 
    <a href={{link}}> {{link}} </a>
{{/if}}

Comment: That would work, or you can just have an `{{else}}` in the middle there.